# Windows Batch file - getting user input but only the first command gets executed

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have windows batch script which is used to get user input. Its like a menu with multiple options shown to the user. When the first option is given it works fine. But when i give the second option too, it executes the first only. What is the issue here?
CODE:

```
@echo off
:Menu
echo 1. OPTION1

echo 2. OPTION2
echo.

set /P INPUT=Enter your choice: %=%
If "%INPUT%" =="1" goto ONE
If "%INPUT%" =="2" goto TWO

:ONE
some commands..........
goto end
PAUSE
:TWO
some commands..........
goto end
PAUSE

:end
pause
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to execute both?

Comment: I am not saying it should execute both at the same time, I am saying when the user is giving input as '2', it should only execute the code under 'TWO' which is not happening. It executes code under 'ONE' only irrespective of the input given. Why is the question here?

Comment: The way you worded the question strongly implies that you expected to be able to input "1 2" and have it execute both.

Comment: I have mentioned its a menu with multiple options shown to the user. There is a statement in the code asking "Enter your choice:". If I wanna execute both why should I be asking for input? Even then why would there be a statement asking for choice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified it to goto end in each instance regardless of answer 1 or 2, this means if you put an answer on 1 it will go to 1 then execute then goto end, if you put 2 the same would happen but it would goto 2 then to end.

Comment: I understand that. Your statement : "if you put 2 the same would happen but it would goto 2 then to end." -- this is not happening which is my concern. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Change where it says some commands to "echo section 1" on the first section and "echo section 2" on the second, I have literally just copied your command and it works fine

Comment: Tried but for me even when i input '2', it says "section 1"

Comment: Could it be system dependent?

Comment: Very highly doubtful, paste this into a batch file and see what happens

@echo off
:Menu
echo 1. OPTION1

echo 2. OPTION2
echo.

set /P INPUT=Enter your choice: %=%
If "%INPUT%" =="1" goto ONE
If "%INPUT%" =="2" goto TWO

:ONE
some commands..........
goto end
PAUSE
:TWO
some commands..........
goto end
PAUSE

:end
pause

Comment: FOUND IT! Was very simple. Its not accepting variable name in CAPS. When i changed it from INPUT to input, it works!

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT! Was very simple. Its not accepting variable name in CAPS. When i changed it from INPUT to input, it works!

Comment: That doesn't seem right, variable names are case-insensitive in batch files.  Care to post the code that is now working? - From your question I'd have guessed INPUT wasn't ==1 or ==2, therefore it carries on without hitting a GOTO statement and arrives at the :ONE label.  (Which you have made a default since there is nothing to cater for input isn't 1 or 2 - was that intended?)

Comment: Batch varaible names don't care if they are capitalized or not. %VAR%, %var%, %VaR%. %vAr%,... they all are the same. You must have corrected another error (that isn't in your question, because that code runs fine) by accident. That said, take a look to `choice /?`

Comment: Yes.. I was also under the same impression that variables are not case-sensitive but somehow thats the only change I made which got it to work